# How to mock a property

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, python-mock

I'm asking how to mock a class property in a unit test using Python 3. I've tried the following, which makes sense for me following the docs, but it doesn't work:

*foo.py:*

```
class Foo():
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return 'foobar'


def test_foo_bar(mocker):
    foo = Foo()
    mocker.patch.object(foo, 'bar', new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock)
    print(foo.bar)
```

I've installed `pytest` and `pytest_mock` and run the test like this:

```
pytest foo.py
```

I got the following error:

```
>       setattr(self.target, self.attribute, new_attr)
E       AttributeError: can't set attribute

/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py:1312: AttributeError
```

My expectation would be that the test runs without errors.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The property mechanism relies on the property attribute being defined on the object's class. You can't create a "property like" method or attribute on a single instance of a class (for a better understanding, read about Python's [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors))

Therefore you have to apply the patch to your class - you can use the `with` statement so that the class is properly restored after your test:

```
def test_foo_bar(mock):
    foo = Foo()
    with mock.patch(__name__ + "Foo.bar", new=mocker.PropertyMock)
        print(foo.bar)
```

Comment: That works! Also thanks for the link about the descriptor protocol. Indeed, I don't understand how properties are implemented under the hood so far. Will go through that.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly return the value if you do not need extra features

```
from mock import patch

@patch('foo.Foo.bar', 'mocked_property_value')
def test_foo_bar():
    foo = Foo()    
    print(foo.bar)
```

Or you can wrap MagicMocks with a call to function `property`:

```
from mock import patch, MagicMock

@patch('foo.Foo.bar', property(MagicMock(return_value='mocked_property_value')))
def test_foo_bar():
    foo = Foo()    
    print(foo.bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way is to take advantage of PropertyMock and MagicMock;  The following works great:

```
def test_foo_bar():

    mockedFoo: MagicMock = MagicMock(spec=Foo)

    type(mockedFoo).bar = PropertyMock(return_value='Mocked foobar')

    print(mockedFoo.bar)
```